# Trying to vertically align two elements inside a div with a fixed height

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to simply align two elements vertically, they are inside a div. I have several images that all have different heights.

**HTML**

```
<div class="companyBox">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/145x150/555555/000000&text=image" />

    <div class="showPlans">
        <p>Show Plans</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.companyBox {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #999;
    text-align: center;
}
.companyBox img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.companyBox .showPlans {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/hQab5/

Thank you for any help, I don't understand why I am having trouble with something that I would have considered simple.

Comment: It isn't an exact duplicate, looks like the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WST8/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="companyBox">

    <div class="showPlans">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/145x150/555555/000000&text=image" />
        <p>Show Plans</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.companyBox {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #999;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.companyBox img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.companyBox .showPlans {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: transforming your parent div to `display:table` and giving child div's `display:table-cell` otherwise you can't vertical align

Comment: an alternative using `vertical-align` could also be setting `your line-height` as big as the size the container.